# passing contextual filter arguments to views via service end points

Tags: drupal, service, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters

I created a view that has contextual filter. Then I created a service (using Services module) to serve up views. For example, let's say my service name is search, and my view name is zoos with a contextual filter city. The following url will return the correct contents:
http:/?q=search/views/zoos.json
http:/?q=zoos/Austin

But if I do the following:
http:/?q=search/views/zoos.json/Austin
I will get 404 response.

How do I pass arguements to a view when using service? I'm using 7.10 with 3.1 for Services and Views.

I'd appreciate all of your response.

Comment: Mayby this will help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7591/drupal-services-node-filtering

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get contextual filters to work on the "views" resource in the service. I originally tried to create a "service view" and sleect it as the resource but wasnt able to get the endpoint to register my arguments either. If done as a a regular views resurce and specifying the view_id it worked like a charm.

THis seems to be a bug in the module but i wasnt able to devote time to chase it down since the alternative worked for me.